# 'was' vs 'have been'

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

What's the difference?

> I was at home all day

and

> I've been at home all day

Google translate doesn't see the difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

The first uses the past tense, the second is perfect.  You might want to look at the "usual" differences between the past and perfect.

You might say "I was at home all day last Wednesday"  (talking about a time in the past). You couldn't use the perfect in that context.

But if you mean "I (was/have been) at home until now"  it would be natural to make the connection to the present by using the present perfect "have been".